# Using 2 IDs for fragment identifier targeting that differ only by case. According to spec, is it ok in HTML5?

Tags: html, anchor, specifications

In HTML 4, anchors names (whether specified using `id` on `name` attributes) that differ only by case [must not appear in the same document.](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2.1) However, in HTML5 this appears not to be the case.

See the following which describes how browsers should navigate to the "ID exactly equal to decoded fragid" or "name attribute whose value is exactly equal to fragid" (a sidenote regarding the latter -- the `name` attribute isn't supposed to be used in `A` elements in HTML5, but browsers are still apparently expected to deal with it):

> 5. If there is an element in the DOM that has an [ID](http://w3c.github.io/html/webappapis.html#id) exactly equal to *decoded fragid*, then the first such element in [tree order](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#tree-order) is [the indicated part of the document](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#an-indicated-part-of-the-document); stop the algorithm here.
> 6. *No decoded fragid*: If there is an [`<a>`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/textlevel-semantics.html#elementdef-a) element in the DOM that has a `name` attribute whose value is exactly equal to *fragid* (not *decoded fragid*), then the first such element in [tree order](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#tree-order) is [the indicated part of the document](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#an-indicated-part-of-the-document); stop the algorithm here.

[— "HTML 5.2
W3C Recommendation", 14 December 2017 - §6.7.9. Navigating to a fragment](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#navigating-to-a-fragment-identifier)

And see the following regarding valid ID names:

> When specified on [HTML elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#html-element), the [`id`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-attrdef-global-id) attribute value must be unique amongst all the [IDs](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-id) in the element’s [tree](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#tree) and must contain at least one character. The value must not contain any [space characters](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#space-characters).
>
> > NOTE:
> >
> > The [`id`](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#element-attrdef-global-id) attribute specifies its element’s [unique identifier (ID)](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-id).
> >
> > There are no other restrictions on what form an ID can take; in particular, IDs can consist of just digits, start with a digit, start with an underscore, consist of just punctuation, etc.
> >
> > An element’s [unique identifier](https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-id) can be used for a variety of purposes, most notably as a way to link to specific parts of a document using [fragment](https://url.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-url-fragment), as a way to target an element when scripting, and as a way to style a specific element from CSS.

[— "HTML 5.2 W3C Recommendation", 14 December 2017](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#ref-for-html-element%E2%91%A0%E2%91%A2)

So am I correct in interpreting all this to mean that according to spec, uppercase and lowercase IDs in the same document should no longer conflict? That is, is it true both that

1. it's permissible for content writers to have `id="A"` and `id="a"` in the same document, and
2. browsers are required to differentiate between "#A" and "#a" in navigating to different indicated parts of the same document?

I ask because I was seeing some behavior in a browser that still didn't follow this (at least for URLs entered via the URL bar), and I don't want to bother them by submitting it as a bug if it isn't one.

Comment: I don't see anything here that would indicate that only differing by case is allowed.

Comment: Your analysis looks spot on to me.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Why? The description in HTML5 for valid IDs in the latter excerpt makes no reference to case, unlike the HTML 4.01 specification I linked at the beginning. Why would there be a case restriction if that's not said anywhere, and it explicitly says "there are no other restrictions"? The only rules stated are that it must contain at least one character, cannot contain spaces, and must be a unique identifier. I see nothing in the section linked to by "unique identifier" ( https://www.w3.org/TR/dom/#concept-id ) that makes reference to alphabetic characters having special treatment.

Comment: Primarily, because just about every user agent I know of will treat `id`s that differ only by case as identical.

Comment: Have you bothered to actually test that? https://jsfiddle.net/z1oyemgp/  Your claim is proven untrue in Chrome or Firefox, and that's just what I'm testing from my phone right now...